# Autostart C++ compiled application upon boot

Tags: c++, autostart, startup-applications

I made a C++ application.

The app just gives me terminal output (just to be sure that my script has launched properly). There is no GUI. I want my app to run when my computer is booted. My script streams video via Ethernet.

I would like to run it at startup. Currently, what I do in terminal is:

```
cd /home/myproject/build
./myapp
```

How can I execute these commands automatically at startup on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the default Ubuntu flavor so you have `gnome-terminal` as your terminal emulator.

To run an executable that outputs to the terminal at startup, you can create a `myapp.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart` containing the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -e /home/<username>/myproject/build/myapp
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Enabled=true
Name=myapp
Comment=My awesome video streaming app.
```

Don't forget to change `<username>` with the actual value of your UNIX username, which you can get by running `whoami` in a terminal window.

The most important lines in this `.desktop` file are the `Exec` line (the command line of the program to run) and the `X-GNOME-Autostart-Enabled` line (whether it runs at startup or not). It launches a terminal window (`gnome-terminal -e`) and runs your compiled app. You can customize the lines beginning with `Name` and `Comment` to your liking.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `crontab` with the `@reboot` modifier as the neatest solution, but it doesn't output to terminal, you can output it to an email though. Cron allows tasks to be scheduled based on time or on reboot.

Command:

```
crontab -e
```

Select nano as the editor. (or your preferred option)
Then add:

```
MAILTO="youremail@emailprovider"
@reboot cd /home/myproject/build && ./myapp
```

To the file.

You can also run commands @hourly, @daily, @yearly or at specific times during the week or month.

Also, add `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file to send commands to the correct shell